# Выделение всех checkbox в колонке?

Tags: jquery

```html
<table class="tftable" border="1">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <th>#</th>
      <th>
        <img src="/templates/pokupatel/images/icons/Белая техника.png" alt="Белая техника" style="width: 70px; height: 70px;"><br>
        <span>Белая техника</span>
        <br> <input type="checkbox" name="category" id="check_all">
      </th>
      <th>
        <img src="/templates/pokupatel/images/icons/Встроенная техника.png" alt="Встроенная техника" style="width: 70px; height: 70px;"><br>
        <span>Встроенная техника</span>
        <br> <input type="checkbox" name="category" id="check_all">
      </th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <img src="" alt="{name}" style="width: 215px; height: 70px;"><br>
        <span class="title">Компания #2</span> <br>
        <span class="adress"></span> <br>
        <span class="phone"></span> <br>
        <span class="site"></span> <br>
      </td>
      <td id="check_all">
        <input class="checkbox" type="checkbox" name="category">
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type="checkbox" name="category">
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <img src="/uploads/posts/2018-07/1530961289_mvideo_1996.png" alt="{name}" style="width: 215px; height: 70px;"><br>
        <span class="title">Компания #1</span> <br>
        <span class="adress">Весенняя 54</span> <br>
        <span class="phone">+79526036525</span> <br>
        <span class="site">http://pokupatel.pro</span> <br>
      </td>
      <td id="check_all">
        <input class="checkbox" type="checkbox" name="category">
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type="checkbox" name="category">
      </td>
    </tr>

  </tbody>
</table>
```

Как сделать что б при нажатии на checkbox белой техники, выделялись все checkbox в этой колонке, а при нажатии встроенной техники, нажималась вся колонка с ней и т.д.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
$("table.tftable tr th input[type='checkbox']").change(function() {
  var index = $(this).closest("th").index();
  $("table.tftable tr td:nth-child(" + (index + 1) + ") input[type='checkbox']").prop("checked", this.checked);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="tftable" border="1">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <th>#</th>
      <th>
        <span>Белая техника</span>
        <br> <input type="checkbox" name="category" id="check_all">
      </th>
      <th>
        <span>Встроенная техника</span>
        <br> <input type="checkbox" name="category" id="check_all">
      </th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <span class="title">Компания #2</span> <br>
        <span class="adress"></span> <br>
        <span class="phone"></span> <br>
        <span class="site"></span> <br>
      </td>
      <td id="check_all">
        <input class="checkbox" type="checkbox" name="category">
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type="checkbox" name="category">
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <span class="title">Компания #1</span> <br>
        <span class="adress">Весенняя 54</span> <br>
        <span class="phone">+79526036525</span> <br>
        <span class="site">http://pokupatel.pro</span> <br>
      </td>
      <td id="check_all">
        <input class="checkbox" type="checkbox" name="category">
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type="checkbox" name="category">
      </td>
    </tr>

  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: привет. Помоги еще Как сделать чтобы функция работала с двумя разными checkbox?

Comment: @Never3D Я не способен догадаться, что это значит.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/5ag2muno/ вот  тут два чекбокса В наличии, Под заказ. Но  выше  скрипт работает только с одним

Comment: Помогите пожалуйста

Comment: @Never3D Давайте отдельный вопрос, и будем разбираться.

Comment: Вот https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/871102/%D0%92%D1%8B%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%B2%D1%81%D0%B5%D1%85-%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BA%D0%B1%D0%BE%D0%BA%D1%81-%D0%B2-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%BA%D0%B5-%D1%81-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%B4%D1%83%D1%8E%D1%89%D0%B8%D0%BC-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BD%D1%8F%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%B5%D0%BC-%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%B8