# Выделение всех чекбокс в колонке, с последующим поднятием строки

Tags: jquery

Нужно всего лишь, чтоб при нажатии на чекбокс (в наличии или под заказ) в заголовке происходило выделение всех чекбоксов (в наличии или под заказ) в колонке, с последующим поднятием строки. Сейчас к сожалению работает только с чекбоксом в наличии, а под заказ нет.

```js
var $table = $('table.tftable');
$table.on('change', '.chk-all', function() {
  var
    index = $(this).closest('th').index() + 1,
    selector = `td:nth-child(${index}) input[type="checkbox"]`,
    checked = this.checked;

  $table.find(`tr ${selector}`).prop('checked', checked);
  $table.find('tr').slice(1).detach().sort(function(a, b) {
    var
      $a = $(a),
      $b = $(b),
      aGreen = $a.find(selector).hasClass('green'),
      bGreen = $b.find(selector).hasClass('green'),
      greenDiff = getNumGreenCheckedInRow($b) - getNumGreenCheckedInRow($a);

    return greenDiff
      ? greenDiff
      : (bGreen ^ aGreen)
        ? [1, -1][+(checked ^ bGreen)]
        : 0;
    
  }).appendTo($table);
});


function getNumGreenCheckedInRow($row) {
  return $row
    .find('.green')
    .closest('td')
    .toArray()
    .map(n => $(n).index())
    .filter(n => $table.find(`tr:eq(0) th:eq(${n}) input:checked`).length).length;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/5ag2muno/4/

Comment: Приведите код в вопросе полностью с html разметкой

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/5ag2muno/16/

Comment: Не на сторонних ресурсах, а здесь. Чтобы в случае чего, код сохранился. Правила

Answer (score 0):

Я сделал для столбца - `"Встроенная техника"`, но принцип, надеюсь, понятен.

https://jsfiddle.net/5ag2muno/15/

Comment: Понял. А сразу ко всем нельзя?

Comment: не работает https://jsfiddle.net/5ag2muno/16/

Comment: @Never3D Мой пример со столбцом "Встроенная техника" работает? Что значит "не работает"?

Comment: Вот тут https://jsfiddle.net/5ag2muno/18/ не работает, не подымает((

Comment: Что делать? скажите пожалуйста

Comment: @Never3D Я пока все-таки не пойму - в чем проблема. В моем jsfiddle - колонка "Встроенная техника" работает. Вам надо сделать для других колонок. Принцип Вы поняли?

Comment: почти понял, присвоить класс order на заказ и available в наличии? и также добавить чекбоксам data-inventory="available" и data-inventory="order". Это все?

Comment: @Never3D Да. Это все, что я сделал в Вашем jsfiddle, плюс небольшое изменение в значении переменной `selector` в коде обработчика события.

Comment: Так вот я про это и говорю, я все это сделал. Выделяются в налиичии, но не подымаются

Comment: вот http://joxi.ru/BA0NpVqcJN6M8m

Comment: помогите пожалуйста